# ExtractSURF always returning the same direction

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm just trying to start learning OpenCV. My understanding is ExtractSURF should return an angle between 0 and 360. For some reason keypoints always returning a direction of 90 for me. Any ideas why?

This code:

```
import cv
image = cv.LoadImageM('lena.bmp', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
(keypoints, descriptors) = cv.ExtractSURF(image, None, cv.CreateMemStorage(), (0, 6000, 1, 3))
for keypoint in keypoints:
    ((x, y), laplacian, size, dir, hessian) = keypoint
    print "x=%d y=%d laplacian=%d size=%f dir=%f hessian=%f" % (x, y, laplacian, size, dir, hessian)
```

returns

```
x=345 y=201 laplacian=1 size=22.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=6674.604492
x=82 y=270 laplacian=-1 size=18.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=7615.113770
x=90 y=278 laplacian=-1 size=15.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=12525.487305
x=112 y=254 laplacian=1 size=22.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=8894.154297
x=273 y=274 laplacian=-1 size=24.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=16313.005859
x=154 y=319 laplacian=-1 size=15.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=9818.360352
x=172 y=333 laplacian=-1 size=26.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=8314.745117
x=137 y=386 laplacian=-1 size=15.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=9148.833984
x=140 y=363 laplacian=-1 size=22.000000 dir=90.000000 hessian=7735.985840
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `_upright` parameter, which tells OpenCV whether to compute the angles or not.  So I assume OpenCV decides to just return 90 degrees if you do not specify it.  I can't remember if there is a way to specify it in the older `cv` interface.  In the newer `cv2` interface, however, it is very easy:

```
import cv2
```

Specify your desired SURF-parameters:

```
surf_params = {"_hessianThreshold":1000,
 "_nOctaves":4, 
"_nOctaveLayers":2, 
"_extended":1, 
"_upright":0}
```

Note that passing `upright` as `1` will always return angles of `90`.

Construct SURF-object and read image:

```
surf = cv2.SURF(**surf_params)
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
(keypoints, descriptors) = surf.detect(image, mask=None, useProvidedKeypoints=False)

for keypoint in keypoints:
    x,y = keypoint.pt
    size = keypoint.size 
    orientation = keypoint.angle
    response = keypoint.response 
    octave = keypoint.octave
    class_id = keypoint.class_id
    print (x,y), size, orientation
```

An example of what this returns for (x,y), size, orientation: (I am using a different image)

```
(523.3077392578125, 933.419189453125) 156.0 199.023590088
(1417.82470703125, 957.7914428710938) 166.0 127.772354126
(1398.8065185546875, 971.0693359375) 165.0 126.83026123
(1009.0242309570312, 1032.0604248046875) 176.0 164.367050171
```

And that's it.  This is one of many reasons why I always advise people to switch to the newer `cv2` interface.  Since I made the switch, I haven't had to deal with stuff like missing parameters anymore.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Works well. Thanks for the help! It looks like most examples on the web use cv instead of cv2. Any suggestions on where I should look to learn about cv2?

Comment: In general I find that the two are very similar, except that `cv2` is more intuitive for a Python user.  You may refer to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/core.html) or [the reference manual](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman.pdf), but most of the time I just end up using Google to find what I need.  OpenCV is not as completely documented as we would like, unfortunately!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't realize the python bindings were in the reference manual. That should help quite a bit.